# Diff of list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Need input on finding diff of 2 list of dictionaries.

For example between 2 list below

```
master_list = {'UDP-MIB': ['udpOutDatagrams',
             'udpInDatagrams'],
 'VRRP-MIB': ['vrrpNodeVersion', 'vrrpNotificationCntl']}

found_list = {'UDP-MIB': ['udpLocalAddress',
             'udpHCOutDatagrams',
             'udpNoPorts'],
 'VRRP-MIB': ['vrrpNodeVersion', 'vrrpNotificationCntl']}
```

Will difflib or jsondiff helps ?

Comment: Can you please tell me the expected output ?

Comment: The keys in both dicts are same. However the values of the first key differs from the second. What is your desired output?

Comment: Need diff of values with same keys

Comment: Btw, you have two dictionaries of lists, not lists of dictionaries.

Comment: For dictionaries with lists, just compare the [key views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which are sets, then compare the values. You need to narrow this down to specifics, because 'differences' is too broad a definition.

Comment: @agnel, you may consider accepting the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 2):

Using [`dictdiffer`](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/dictdiffer):

```
import dictdiffer
master_list = {'UDP-MIB': ['udpOutDatagrams', 'udpInDatagrams'],
               'VRRP-MIB': ['vrrpNodeVersion', 'vrrpNotificationCntl']}

found_list = {'UDP-MIB': ['udpLocalAddress', 'udpHCOutDatagrams', 'udpNoPorts'],
              'VRRP-MIB': ['vrrpNodeVersion', 'vrrpNotificationCntl']}

for diff in list(dictdiffer.diff(master_list, found_list)):
    print(diff)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
('change', ['UDP-MIB', 0], ('udpOutDatagrams', 'udpLocalAddress'))
('change', ['UDP-MIB', 1], ('udpInDatagrams', 'udpHCOutDatagrams'))
('add', 'UDP-MIB', [(2, 'udpNoPorts')])
```

**Note**:

> A diff is a tuple with the type of change, the changed value, and the
>   path to the entry.